# Not able to IPv6-tunnel using miredo for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, ipv6, teredo

I have been trying to setup Miredo on OS X 10.7.5 using the [Miredo Installer for OS X](http://www.deepdarc.com/miredo-osx/)

When Miredo starts after installation, the check box next to the "Teredo Tunnel" is still red and I am not able to connect or ping IPv6 sites.

Has anybody succeeded in using IPv6 tunneling using the Miredo package for OS X?

Comment: Don't bother with this. It's ancient, doesn't work on 64-bit Macs, and Teredo is a very poor choice for IPv6 tunneling anyway. Get a tunnel from SixXS or Hurricane Electric.

Answer (score -1):

Install tap/tun driver for mac.http://sourceforge.net/projects/tuntaposx/?source=pdlp